# Function only works when URL is called manually?

Tags: php, function, include, scope

I've been smashing my head against a wall over this for the last 3 hours.

I have a short script I wrote up a while ago for routine maintenance of a PHP/MySQL application.  The problem is not with the script itself.  I can call this PHP script by its URL manually and it executes fine and does what it is supposed to.  The problem is that I have tried to include the script in the application when a certain event happens to have it run and it won't work.

I get the fatal Cannot use string offset as an array only in function error with the following line:
$ingredientID = $prepItems[$i]['ingredientID'];

I understand the error means you assign a string and then try to treat it as an array, but $ingredientID has not been declared anywhere in the function before this line, and $prepItems[$i]['ingredientID'] is itself a string anyway! I checked and $prepItems is returned correctly.  When I go back and call the URL the script works, when I try to include it from inside another script in the application it won't work.  I don't get it....

The full code is below....

```
//UPDATE PRODUCTION NUMBERS

function fixOrders(){

$k = 0;
$date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('yesterday'));

$qry = "SELECT a.orderID,a.qty,a.date,a.itemID,b.itemName,b.itemType FROM orders a join items b on a.itemID = b.itemID WHERE a.date > '$date' AND a.itemID = '$itemID'";
$res = mysql_query($qry);
$qry = "INSERT INTO prep (orderID,dateProd,qty,itemID,dept) VALUES ";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
$itemID = $row['itemID'];
$qty = $row['qty'];
$itemType = $row['itemType'];
$date = $row['date'];
$orderID = $row['orderID'];
$prepItems = prepItems($itemID);
if ($prepItems) removePrepItems($orderID);
$cp = count($prepItems);

if ($prepItems)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < $cp; $i++)
    {               
        $ingredientID = $prepItems[$i]['ingredientID'];
        $ingredientWeight = $prepItems[$i]['ingredientWeight'];
        $ingredientUnit = $prepItems[$i]['ingredientUnit'];
        $productionOffset = $prepItems[$i]['productionOffset']; 
        $qty = ($ingredientWeight * $qty);
        if ($ingredientUnit == 'lbs') $qty = ($qty * 16);
        $date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date.' +'.$productionOffset.' days'));
        echo $date.' '.$productionOffset.'<br>';
        $qry .= "('$orderID','$date','$qty','$ingredientID','$itemType'),";
    }   
    $k++;
}   
}
$qry = substr($qry,0,-1);
mysql_query($qry);
echo $qry;
}

fixOrders($itemID)
```

Comment: could be function fixOrders() was overwritten by another script somewhere when included into that file??

Comment: Before the line where you get the error, try `var_dump($prepItems);`. Make sure that both `$prepItems` AND `$prepItems[$i]` are arrays.

Comment: Venu:  How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `$prepItems` variable/function. Insert a `var_dump` to see what you're actually looking at.

```
...
$cp = count($prepItems);

var_dump($prepItems);

if ($prepItems)
{
...
```

Comment: The strange thing is I did...  I get the expected result.

Comment: @JohnnyMnemonic Please post that output.